# Strange error while converting minutes to hours

Tags: r, chron

I was using the command below to convert minutes (e.g. 366) to hours and minutes format (e.g. 6:06) when I came across a strange error:

```
library(chron) #https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chron/chron.pdf

sub(":\\d{2}", "", times((X%/%60 +  X%%60 /3600)/24))
```

I assign a vector in the place of X in the actual code, for now I will just use a number. For example:

```
sub(":\\d{2}", "", times((240.8%/%60 +  240.8%%60 /3600)/24))
```

Yields "04:01" as it should be. However, the same command with 419.8 minutes wrongly gives "6:00"?

```
sub(":\\d{2}", "", times((419.8%/%60 +  419.8%%60 /3600)/24))
```

When I re-run it without the digit, 419, it is correct again. "06:59". I re-ran the code with random numbers and it seems to be doing fine with others. I can't understand the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't publish an ***image*** of your code/console, just paste the text itself.

Comment: Where does the `times()` function come from?

Comment: It comes from "chron"

Comment: This is a regex problem, nothing to do with `chron` or `times`. Check the output of your calls to `times` without the surrounding call to `sub`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(chron)
times((419.8%/%60 +  419.8%%60 /3600)/24)
# [1] 06:01:00
times((419%/%60 +  419%%60 /3600)/24)
# [1] 06:00:59
```

The problem is in your `sub` regex. Try:

```
sub(":\\d{2}$", "", times((419%/%60 +  419%%60 /3600)/24))
# [1] "06:00"
sub(":\\d{2}$", "", times((419.8%/%60 +  419.8%%60 /3600)/24))
# [1] "06:01"
```

**Update**:

Additionally, your math is *incorrectly* converting minutes to seconds. Try:

```
times((419.8%/%60 +  419.8%%60 / 60)/24)
# [1] 06:59:48
sub(":\\d{2}$", "", times((419.8%/%60 +  419.8%%60 / 60)/24))
# [1] "06:59"
```

Comment: Thanks! But shouldn't the right outcome of 419 minutes be 06:59 instead of 6:01, as 419 minutes corresponds to 6 hours and 59 minutes. In this version, for example, both 300 and 359 minutes gives : "05:00". Maybe I did this all wrong.